# Can a morphed non-nothlit use the Escafil Device again to get morphing powers in the morph?

Tags: animorphs, morphing

Case 1: Get a morph, get morphing powers again, get another morph and be able to keep switching through first level and second level morphs all the time without needing to morph through the original body to remorph.

**+**...**<** **[** **{** original body **}** first level morph **]** second level morph **>** ...**+**

Case 2: Get a morph, get morphing powers again, get another morph but must be within the time limits of the first level morph to not get stuck as a nothlit in the first level morph.

Comment: [This related answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65845) suggests that it isn't possible for a morphed form to acquire the ability to morph. I don't think it was ever directly addressed, though.

Comment: @Cadence It says that a nothlit can't use it but it doesn't directly imply that either of the two cases are outright wrong. It implies that there may be a lock or a degradation within the technology that is renewed after another morphing within the being takes place, but as you said, it may have never been directly addressed.
So, could it be either to a second level morph or back to the original body. That's why I'm asking.  .  .  .  .  However, the case 2 is also not adressed, where you morph from a first level morph to a second level morph within the time limits of the first level morph.